# JSTL как добавить тэг?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jstl

Как сделать, чтобы в начале каждой строки отображался checkbox? Т.е. смысл такой у меня выводится таблица с контактами я отмечаю те что хочу удалить и передаю дальше эти значения в запрос на удаление контакта из базы. Вариант ниже не работает.

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from users;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Age</th>
   <th>Sex</th>
   <th>Phone number</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" checked="" /></td>

   <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.last_name}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.sex}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.phone_number}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Попробуйте дать чекбоксам имя "id[]" Тогда по сабмиту по идее уйдет массив имен

Comment: спасибо, помогло, а можно поподробней пожалуйста, хочу разобраться.

Comment: Кстати, возможен и другой способ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016272/how-to-post-multiple-record-sets-from-an-html-form-to-jsp-or-a-java-servlet